# client_socket.listen() OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: sockets

I am trying socket programming
i am recieving this error

```
  File "python/sockpractice/client1.py", line 5, in <module>
    client_socket.listen()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

*client code is

```
import socket

client_socket=socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
client_socket.listen()
conn, addr=client_socket.accept()

while True:
    conn.recv(1024)
    string=input('#> ')
    conn.send(string.encode())
```

And server code is

```
server_socket=socket.socket()
host='127.0.0.1'
port=8080
binder=(host, port)

server_socket.bind(binder)
server_socket.listen()

connection, address=server_socket.accept()
while True:
    string=input('#> ')
    connection.send(string.encode())
    connection.recv(1024)
```

- 

Please help me

What can i do to solve this problem

Comment: Your client should not be calling `listen()` or `accept()` at all, only `connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `listen` call on the client. In general only the server side calls `listen`.